# flutter focus on a CupertinoTextField after pushing to the route which contains that field

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have an tab based app with multi navigation stacks for each tab (using CupertinoTabScaffold)

i'm trying to focus on a CupertinoTextField after I push to a route that has the field with:

screen 1:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => SearchResultPage(),
));
```

screen 2:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focus);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

this code works but if I remove the timer I get an error which says:

```
flutter: When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent
flutter: widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor
flutter: or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the
flutter: inherited widget.
flutter: Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively,
flutter: initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which
flutter: is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined in flutter docs for *initState* method:

> Override this method to perform initialization that depends on the location at which this object was inserted into the tree (i.e., context) or on the widget used to configure this object (i.e., widget).

This means this function is used for initialization and it runs before the build method is even called, so when you remove the timer, you are actually trying to get focus on a widget which is not yet built/rendered according the framework. That's why the error.

Comment: oh I see what you mean, but any solution to this?!

Comment: Depends on how you are doing the state management? If you are using redux, and you want the focus on the widget as soon as it is rendered, then you can just use **onDidChange**. And yes autofocus property will also do for the widget.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is already quite explicit on what you would need to do to fix this:

```dart
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies () {
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focus);
    });
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

@override
void dispose() {
  _timer?.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

also you would need to make sure to properly discard this `Timer` (as shown in the example above).

But there is also an easier way to auto focus a textfield, as documented in the [cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus):

> To give focus to a text field as soon as it’s visible, use the autofocus property.
>
> ```
> TextField(
>   autofocus: true,
> );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, with a small timeout.

```
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  FocusNode _node = FocusNode();

  // ....

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 350)).then((_) {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_node);
    });
  }
```

and attach the node to your text widget as necessary, e.g.:

```
CupertinoSearchTextField(
  focusNode: _node,
)
```